# (OSStatus error 2003334207) Playing from file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avaudioplayer, swift3

I am receiving this error:

> (OSStatus error 2003334207)

while trying to play a song from a path, the path is valid as I can play the mp3 from the directory but I cannot get it to play in the audio player, the path looks like this -

`file:///XXXX/XXXX/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1ECD7193-872E-4108-A565-F12BED6A69E0/data/Containers/Data/Application/85FD4AD1-54AF-4AD1-81A2-3BDA5CCE9D0A/Documents/Blessings.mp3`

```
let vc = ViewController()
var myAudioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

var downloadName = [String]()
var songDest = [String]()
var nameMusicFile = String()
var mp3Url : URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print(downloadName)
    print(songDest)
    let convert = URL(fileURLWithPath: songDest[0])
    playMusic(url: convert)
    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
}


func playMusic(url: URL) {

    let path = url as URL!
    do {


    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)

    try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)
    try myAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: path!)
    myAudioPlayer.volume = 1
    myAudioPlayer.play()
    } catch let err as NSError{
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally this error occurs when you are trying to access the file which is not present in the specified folder or try to unwrap the variable which has nil value. 
Pl. check if the fetchedResultController is returning an object.